# I don't have any clue how to use for loops and it's really bad

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm working on an assignment for my java course and this program won't seem to work. The instructions are:

> Obtain a number n greater than 5 and less than 20 from the console/user. Verify that the number meets the requirements. Print a descending number of stars, first row is n stars then replace each star with a number until the last row is all numbers. Leave a space between each star and /or number. Here is an example.
>
> ###### n = 5
>
> ```
> * * * * * 
> 1 * * * *
> 1 2 * * *
> 1 2 3 * *
> 1 2 3 4 *
> 1 2 3 4 5
> ```

Here's what I tried:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

// Obtain a number from the user between 5 and 20
System.out.print("Enter a number greater than 5 and less than 20: ");
int n = input.nextInt();

if (n < 5 || n > 20) {
System.out.print("Please insert a number greater than 5 and less than 20");
System.exit(0); } 

// Print descending stars and numbers pattern
for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
    // Print numbers for the stars
    for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; j++) {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }

    // Print stars for the remaining spaces
    for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
        System.out.print("* ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

My output is this:

```
* * * * * * 
1 * * * * * 
1 2 * * * * 
1 2 3 * * * 
1 2 3 4 * * 
1 2 3 4 5 *
```

Comment: You have the very common "off by one" problem.  Your second loop should stop with `k < i`, not `k <= i`.

Answer (score 1):

You had a simple off by one error in your code that caused you to loop once too few when printing the numbers, and once too many when printing the starts.

This code produces the proper output.

```java
            // create scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Obtain a number from the user between 5 and 20
        System.out.print("Enter a number greater than 5 and less than 20: ");
        int n = input.nextInt();

        if (n < 5 || n > 20) {
        System.out.print("Please insert a number greater than 5 and less than 20");
        System.exit(0); } 

        // Print descending stars and numbers pattern
        for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
            // Print numbers for the stars
            for (int j = 1; j <= (n - i) + 1; j++) {
                System.out.print(j + " ");
            }

            // Print stars for the remaining spaces
            for (int k = 1; k <= i - 1; k++) {
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

I promise you, this type of error happens to everyone. It isn't that bad.